# Why my PC turned off unexpectedly?

Tags: 12.04, cpu, overheating

Let me tell the complete story. I have a normal PC with monitor, CPU, UPS, mouse and a keyboard. I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. For the last 15 days my computer is shutting down unexpectedly. Here in my case I can not say that it is exactly shutting down.

When I switch on only my monitor then it shows that 'there is no signal'
this is because I have not turned on my CPU. And so I turned on my CPU. Then my PC started working. 
Few days before when I was working on my PC and it was working normally.
**Then suddenly my monitor turned off and on its screen there was a message that 'there is no signal' but at that time my CPU was on**.
After that when I tuned off my CPU manually then I again tried to start me PC but I failed. After a day when I started it then it worked normally.

Initially I thought that:

1) there may be a problem in my cable wire which connect the monitor and the CPU. But this is not the problem since I have used another cable wire.

2) there may be a problem in my PC. But this is not the problem since I connected my CPU with another monitor, second reason is that if my monitor is having problem then it should not work afterwards but in my case it is working after wards.

3) there may be a problem of overheating but this is also not possible since once it turned of within 5 minutes. And maximum I work on my PC is for 2 hrs.

I have even updated my PC using update manager put then too it is not working well.

I have not taken any help from any technical engineer because:

1) Once when I asked them about Ubuntu then they said that they don't know about Ubuntu and the problem is internal and you must try window.

2) I don't know anybody who know Ubuntu well.

I am posting this question from my PC but I don't know till when it will work well!

Kindly help me to find the problem in my PC.

Comment: Most common reasons I have seen for this behavior are 1. too hot - check the temp in your BIOS, 2. Bad RAM - do a memtest and 3. Buggy drivers in the kernel - boot an old kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the machine is overheating and the CPU was turned off when it hit a thermal trip threshold.  If it is overheating, you could try using thermald which will try and prevent thermal overrun by using various passive cooling mechanisms.  See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues